# Looping through list and row for keyword match in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataframe that looks like this. It has 1 column labeled 'utterances'. `df.utterances` contains rows whose values are strings of n number words.

```html
  
                             utterances
0                                        okay go ahead.
1                                     Um, let me think.
2     nan that's not very encouraging. If they had a...
3     they wouldn't make you want to do it. nan nan ...
4     Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...
```

I also have a list of specific words. It is called `specific_words`. It looks like this:

```html
specific_words = ['happy, 'good', 'encouraging', 'joyful']
```

I want to check if any of the words from `specific_words` are found in any of the utterances. Essentially, I want to loop throughevery row in `df.utterance`, and when I do so, loop through `specific_list` to look for matches. If there is a match, I want to have a boolean column next to df.utterances that shows this.

```html
def query_text_by_keyword(df, word_list):
    for word in word_list:
        for utt in df.utterance:
            if word in utt:
                match = True
            else:
                match = False
            return match
    
df['query_match'] = df.apply(query_text_by_keyword, 
                                               axis=1, 
                                               args=(specific_words,))
```

It doesn't break, but it just returns False for every row, when it shouldn't. For example, the first few rows should look like this:

```html
 utterances                                                    query_match
    0                                        okay go ahead.       False
    1                                     Um, let me think.       False
    2     nan that's not very encouraging. If they had a...       True
    3     they wouldn't make you want to do it. nan nan ...       False
    4     Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...       False
```

#### Edit

@furas made a great suggestion to solve the initial question. However, I would also like to add another column that contains the specific word(s) from the query that indicates a match. Example:

```html
 utterances                                                 query_match   word  
    0                                    okay go ahead    False      NaN
    1                                 Um, let me think    False      NaN
    2 nan that's not very encouraging. If they had a..    True   'encouraging'
    3 they wouldn't make you want to do it. nan nan ..    False      NaN
    4 Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu..    False      NaN
```

Comment: regex - `df.str.constains("happy|good|encouraging|joyful")` ? And `"|".join(specific_words)` to create this regex.

Comment: @connor449 , you can also give a try for flashtext..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` with `str.contains(regex)`

```
df['utterances'].str.constains("happy|good|encouraging|joyful")
```

You can create this `regex` with

```
query = '|'.join(specific_words)
```

You can also use `str.lower()` because strings may have uppercase chars.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'utterances':[
        'okay go ahead',
        'Um, let me think.',
        'nan that\'s not very encouraging. If they had a...',
        'they wouldn\'t make you want to do it. nan nan ...',
        'Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...',
    ]
})

specific_words = ['happy', 'good', 'encouraging', 'joyful']

query = '|'.join(specific_words)

df['query_match'] = df['utterances'].str.lower().str.contains(query)

print(df)
```

Result

```
                                          utterances  query_match
0                                      okay go ahead        False
1                                  Um, let me think.        False
2  nan that's not very encouraging. If they had a...         True
3  they wouldn't make you want to do it. nan nan ...        False
4  Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...        False
```

---

**EDIT:** as @HenryYik mentioned in comment you can use `case=False` instead of `str.lower()`

```
df['query_match'] = df['utterances'].str.contains(query, case=False)
```

More in doc: [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

---

**EDIT:** to get matching word you ca use `str.extract()` with `regex` in `(...)`

```
df['word'] = df['utterances'].str.extract( "(happy|good|encouraging|joyful)" )
```

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'utterances':[
        'okay go ahead',
        'Um, let me think.',
        'nan that\'s not very encouraging. If they had a...',
        'they wouldn\'t make you want to do it. nan nan ...',
        'Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...',
        'Yeah. happy good',
    ]
})

specific_words = ['happy', 'good', 'encouraging', 'joyful']

query = '|'.join(specific_words)

df['query_match'] = df['utterances'].str.contains(query, case=False)
df['word'] = df['utterances'].str.extract( '({})'.format(query) )

print(df)
```

In example I added `'Yeah. happy good'` to test which word will be returned `happy` or `good`. It returns first matching word.

Result:

```
                                          utterances  query_match         word
0                                      okay go ahead        False          NaN
1                                  Um, let me think.        False          NaN
2  nan that's not very encouraging. If they had a...         True  encouraging
3  they wouldn't make you want to do it. nan nan ...        False          NaN
4  Yeah. The problem is though, it just, if we pu...        False          NaN
5                                   Yeah. happy good         True        happy
```

---

**BTW:** now you can even do

```
df['query_match'] = ~df['word'].isna()
```

or

```
df['query_match'] = df['word'].notna()
```

Comment: You could pass `case=False` to `str.contains` so you don't have to lowercase.

Comment: @furas Thanks, this is great. How would you also add another column that held the specific word(s) from the query that were a match? See example in edit above.

Comment: BTW: now you can even do `df['query_match'] = df['word'].notna()` or `df['query_match'] = ~df['word'].isna()`